# Rails: getting results of Ajax request to show in the view?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my index.html.erb, I have a form that submits via Ajax (i think) with `:remote => true`

```
<%= form_tag locations_path, :method => :get, :remote=>true  do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :location, params[:location] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search Near", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

In the index action, it's arranged to set up to return @locations via json

```
def index
     if params[:location].present?
      @locations = Location.near(params[:location], 5 , :order => :distance)

    else
      @locations = Location.all
    end
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @locations }
    end

  end
```

Right now it just returns (i hope) @locations. How do i get the results of @locations in this div in the index.html.erb?

```
<div class="places">  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a slightly different way: using .js respond.
Then it should look something like this:

```
#def index
#some code...
respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.js
end


#index.js.erb
$('.places').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "places_list") %>");


#_places_list.html.erb
<%- @locations.each do |location| %>
  <p><%= location.name %> </p>
<%- end %>
```

The tutorial on this topic: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/

Answer (score 0):

you can bind to the `ajax:success` event on the form element in javascript

see this post for a lengthy explanation: [Rails 3 Remote Links and Forms](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/) by Steve Schwartz

you may also want to replace this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @locations }
end
```

with this

```
respond_with @locations
```

and add this to the top of your controller:

```
respond_to :json
```

Comment: thanks for the reference to that page. Sadly, I can't get it to work. Can you see what a problem with the way I'm rending the @locations variable in the json in my controller?  Due to the setup of my app I can't copy the controller from the page you showed me...

Comment: I added a suggestion to my comment about your response, are you able to see the ajax request happening in the Firebug or Web Inspector console?